# Saving form fields dynamically in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with a lot of inputs.  I do not want to get them one by one. I was thinking about getting them in a loop, or something. So instead of writing this:

```
$page = new Pages(); //my model
$page->title = $request->input('title');
$page->url_name = $request->input('url_name');
$page->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
$page->page_cols = $request->input('page_cols');
//.......... 30 more 
$page->save();
```

I was thinking about using a loop:

```
 foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {
   if ($key != "_token"){
   // assign them to the $page
   }
 }
 $page->save
```

But I m not sure how to do that. IF you have any ideas, please share it with me. Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this:

`Pages::create(Input::all());`

To exclude the token use:

`Input::except('_token')`

You need to fill the property `protected $fillable` for mass assignments. You can read more about it in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

You can add protected $guarded = []; to your model. This makes all fields mass assignable.

Comment: I'm getting this: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException: _token`

Comment: In your model you need to fill the property `protected $fillable = [];`

Comment: @Daan Better add that to your answer and explain why.

Comment: if I use `Pages::create(Input::except('_token'));`  Im getting this: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException: title`

Comment: @Chester add it to the fillable array in your model. I've updated my question with a link to the docs.

Comment: so i still need to add those inputs manually in the $fillable ?

Comment: Not necessary. You can add `protected $guarded = [];` to your model. This makes all fields mass assignable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `create` method to save a new model in a single line as -

```
Pages::create(Input::all());
```

And in your `Pages` model add the `$fillable` property which saves you from a mass-assignment vulnerability which occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter changes a column in your database you did not expect.

For example -

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

Or you can use `$guarded` which is opposite of `$fillable`

```
/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
Pages::create(Input::except('_token'));
```

Comment: Please provide some extra information with your answers along with doc link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Pages::create(Input::all());` will do the trick.

Its basically mass assignment so you have to assign DB table fields to the `protected $fillable = []` array in your related model.

And the opposite of that is `protected $guarded = [];`.

For without token : `Input::except('_token')`.